# How to escape pattern letters in date-fns format

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, datetime-format, date-fns

I need time in the format `xx min, yy seconds`

For which I am doing `format(new Date(99999), 'mm min, ss seconds')` using `date-fns`s `format`.

However it prints `31 31in, 39 39econ439`.

What I want is `1 min, 39 seconds`

So I need 2 things

1. how to escape the `m` in `mins` and `s,d` in `seconds`
2. how to make it count absolute time from epoch rather than adding +5.30 of the timezone

Answer (score 3):

1.) You can escape by using quotes:

```
"mm 'min', ss 'seconds"
```

2.) You need to get the date in unix:

```
Math.round((new Date()). getTime() / 1000);
```

Comment: `format(new Date(99999), "mm 'mins', ss 'seconds' ")` prints `31 '31in39', 39 '39econ439'`

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest version of date-fns. It works fine here: https://repl.it/repls/DismalRadiantInterfaces

Comment: okay, it worked
but why do I get `31 min`?

https://codesandbox.io/s/date-fns-v2-th8dp?file=/src/index.js